# finding which person got highest percentage according to their marks

Tags: python, python-3.x

The first line of the input contains an integer which represents the number of lines

The next `n` lines represent a space-separated list of the person and their marks in the four subjects

output should be name of the highest percentage?

for example
input:-

```
4
Manoj 30 40 45 63
Shivam 38 29 45 60
Siddheshwar 38 35 39 45
Ananya 45 29 30 51
```

Output:-

```
Manoj
```

code :-

```
details_vertical=[]

for ctr in range(4):
    details_vertical.append(input().split())
for name,marks,marks,marks in zip(*details_vertical):
    print(f"{name}")
```

Comment: You can sort the input based on the avg.

Comment: `python3 -> help(max)`

Comment: "name of the highest percentage"?

Comment: the output will have the name of person who got highest percentage out of all other name inputs

Comment: @acelati - review the post, to see if you have any question.  To clarify - I think you're looking for the person of has `highest` score (from your code).  If not, you can make adjustment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something that you're looking for?  Try it first, and ask questions.

There is room to improve it, but this is prob. most straightforward way.

```
details =[]
highest = 0

for i in range(4):
    details  = (input().split())
    print(details)               # just for debug, can comment out

    total = sum(int(x) for x in details[1:])    # get this person's total
    # change this print line to get average printout:
    print(total / len(details[1:])                 # it allows you have n+ scores flexibility - not assuming it's 4 only!
    
    if total > highest:          # processing along the way, so we don't have to save all the scores...
        highest = total
        
        best = details[0]  # the person

print(best)                #  Manoj
```

Comment: Thank you !! instead of showing the sum of the total , how can show percentage of the total ?

Comment: Sure - just see my comment now.  If this post does `answer` your question, please check as your acceptance.

Comment: i=int(input())
details =[]
highest = 0

for i in range(4):
    details  = (input().split())

    total = sum(int(x) for x in details[1:])    
    percentile=((total/4))                 
    
    if percentile > highest:
        
        highest = total
        
        best = details[0]  # the person


print(best)   # thank you soo much for the help :)!!  and i have small doubt on how to get  " The first line of the input contains an integer which represents the number of lines of the second input" . is there any thing i can improve in my code ?

Comment: If that's a test program, it will be something like this:  `N = int(input('lines of inputs: '))`  Then you can use this `N` as to determine in `range(N)`

Comment: Welcome to the new `journey`.  Please ask new questions if you have.  And don't put the `code` in the `comments` section.

Answer (score 0):

is this you are looking for ?

```
input = """4
           Manoj 30 40 45 63
           Shivam 38 29 45 60
           Siddheshwar 38 35 39 45
           Ananya 45 29 30 51"""

# load data from row 1
x = input.split('\n')[1:]
x = [item.split() for item in x]
# append the average of 4 subject in last
y = [item + [sum([int(subitem) for subitem in item[1:]])/4] for item in x]
# sort the row by average
y.sort(key = lambda x:x[-1], reverse=True)
# first row first element is name with highest average
y[0][0]
```

Answer (score -1):

This Solution might be an understandable one :

```
first_inp = int(input("No. of Students"))
no_of_subs = int(input("No. of Subjects :"))
details = {tuple(int(input("Marks")) for i in range(no_of_subs)):input("Name") for i in range(first_inp)}
lis_res = [sum(i) for i in details]
det_val = [v for v in details.values()]
print (det_val[lis_res.index(max(lis_res))])
```

In the end you can use return keyword to return that value if you are defining a function.